# When is Google Music released in the UK?

Tags: android, google-play-music

I know Google Music is already out in the US, but when will it be available in the UK?

And will it be available on Android at the same time?

Comment: You're asking us to speculate; this isn't a good question for this site. I'm sure you can read the [official Google blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com) as well as we can. They're sure to announce when it becomes available elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware that it hadn't been announced yet. I thought I just couldn't find it. If I had known that I wouldn't have asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official [Google Play Help Page](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=play_faq&answer=2490014) explains it as follows:

> Q: What is Google Play?
>   A: Google Play is a new digital content
>   experience from Google where you can find your favorite **music**,
>   movies, books, and Android apps and games.
>
> Q: When will I get Google Play? What markets is this available in?
>   A: We’ll be rolling out Google Play globally starting today. On the
>   web, Google Play will be live today. On devices, it will take a few
>   days for the Android Market app to update to the Google Play Store
>   app. The music, books and movies apps will also receive an update
>   today.
>
> Around the globe, Google Play will include Android apps and games. In
>   countries where we have already launched music, books or movies, you
>   will see those categories available in Google Play, too.
>
> **Q: I live outside the US. When will I get the books, music or movies verticals? I only see Android apps and games?**   A: We want to bring
>   different content categories to as many countries as possible. We’ve
>   already launched movies and books in several countries outside the
>   U.S. and will continue to do so overtime, but **we don’t have a
>   specific timeline** to share.
>
> Q: What types of content are available in my country?
>
> - Paid Apps: Available in [these countries](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?answer=143779)
> - Movies: Available in US, UK, Canada, and Japan
> - eBooks: Available in US, UK, Canada, and Australia
> - Music: Available in US

You may check out the link for more info.